# Run script for many profile path at once in global mapper

Tags: global-mapper

This code when I run it in Global Mapper, that create a .xyz file of profile path between two points

```
GENERATE_PATH_PROFILE \
FILENAME="C:\Users\Bella\Desktop\ProfPath.xyz" \
ELEV_UNITS=METERS \
POINT_SPACING=10.0 \
START_POS=765287.9,3813969.2 \
END_POS=771481.8,3815738.6 \
SAVE_DIST_Z_FILE=YES \
```

1- If I would to create many segments at once, all the segments share the same origin point, how to do it in script, so I can export it all in a file?

2- Could I use the geographic coordinates in `START_POS` and `END_POS` instead of utm projection?

Answer (score 1):

What version of Global Mapper are you using?

For part 2, try entering coordinates in degrees with optional N,S,E,or W appended. 
Washington DC, for example is -77.0364 W,38.8951 N
I think you can also put in other lat/log formats such as
38° 49' 45.9768'' N,  76° 58' 39.1044'' W

For part 1, I would highly suggest contacting Global Mapper support group.